# What is the limit of this complex expression?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

The followings are given for a problem in a book I study :

$$z=Re^{j\theta} \Longrightarrow dz=Re^{j\theta}d\theta$$

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_S \frac{Re^{j\theta}}{1+R^4e^{j4\theta}}d\theta=0$$

where $S$ is a semicircle. However, I believe the correct expressions should be like this:

$$z=Re^{j\theta} \Longrightarrow dz=jRe^{j\theta}d\theta$$

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_S \frac{jRe^{j\theta}}{1+R^4e^{j4\theta}}d\theta$$

Is my limit expression equal to zero again? Does $j$ make any difference?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with complex analysis, but what you have done seems correct to me; but the $j$ is a prefactor which can be pulled out of the limit, and we have $jx = 0 \iff x = 0$ and thus what they are trying to find will be equivalent.

Comment: The complex number $j\neq 0$ is harmless, but you are right: $dz=jRe^{j\theta}\, d\theta$.

Comment: I understand it know thank you for your confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No $j$ doesn't make any difference since it's a constant and multiplying by non zero constant doesn't change the limit.